# Inconsistency when invoke getNeighboringCellInfos()

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I write simple program to get various information: signal strength, cell info etc... To test I use two phones with the same Android version 2.1 - Sony Ericsson and Samsung Galaxy Spice. 
To extract Neighbour Cell Info I use:

```
telephonyConnectionAdapter.getNeighboringCellInfos()
```

On SE I am able to get Neighbour Cell info and in `adb logcat -b radio` I can see:

```
D/GSM     (  488): [GsmSST] Poll ServiceState done:  oldSS=[0 home T-Mobile.pl 
    T-  Mobile.pl 26002  EDGE:2 CSS not supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1 DefRoamInd=-1
    EmergOnly=false] newSS=[0 home T-Mobile.pl T-Mobile.pl 26002  EDGE:2 CSS not
    supported -1 -1 RoamInd=-1 DefRoamInd=-1 EmergOnly=false] oldGprs=0 newData=0
    oldMaxDataCalls=20 mNewMaxDataCalls=20
    oldReasonDataDenied=-1 mNewReasonDataDenied=-1 oldType=EDGE:2 newType=EDGE:2
D/GSM     (  488): [EONS] Reading data from EF_OPL or EF_PNN is not complete.        
    Suppress operator name display until all EF_OPL/EF_PNN data is read.
D/RILJ    (  488): [8847]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILJ    (  488): [8847]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS  [b01b59c7@18 [b01b5260@27] [] [b01b63f9@19] [b01b2f4f@17]
```

but the same application could not extract Neighbour Cell Info on Samsung - the list is empty and `adb logcat -b radio` looks:

```
D/GSM     ( 1993): Poll ServiceState done:  oldSS=[0 home Play Play 26006 (manual)
    EDGE CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoamInd: -1] newSS=[0 home Play Play
    26006 (manual) EDGE CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoamInd: -1] oldGprs=0
    newGprs=0 oldType=EDGE newType=EDGE        D/RILJ    ( 1993): [5590]> REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILC    ( 1855): [5590]> GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS
D/RILC    ( 1855): [5590]< GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS fails by E_REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
D/RILJ    ( 1993): [5590]< REQUEST_GET_NEIGHBORING_CELL_IDS error: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

The is one more important information. When I use magic code `*#*#197328640#*#*` on Samsung and enter to service menu. There are few visible Neighbour Cells.

Any idea what is going on? Or at least what does this mean?

```
"com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED"
```

Answer (score 1):

Each manufacturer implements the low level functionality for their devices as they see fit. In this case, Samsung has decided not to support this feature on this device. This means that you will not be able to get the list of neighboring cells on this device.